# Is this the proper way to use 'ask' in future tense?

Tags: future

> Now imagine, she **asks** him to eat an apple.

Is the above sentence proper? When I say it out loud it sounds weird.

How would you say it out loud? Askkkssss?

Comment: It's certainly seriously sibilant.

Comment: Shouldn't it just be will ask?

Comment: Worth noting that the present tense is much more likely to be appropriate than the future here. “Now imagine she will ask him to eat an apple” sounds quite odd, whereas “Now imagine she asks him to eat an apple” is perfectly unexceptional. So what you have is proper, but not future. Also, if she's asking him to eat an Apple, she's asking him to eat a computer. If it's the fruit you're going for, don't capitalise it.

Comment: And remember that the initial /h/ in _him_ is not normally pronounced when _him_ is unstressed and comes after most consonants, so if it’s easier for you, you can think of it as being pronounced /ask sɪm/ instead of /asks ɪm/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example, "...now imagine, she asks..." is not future tense. It is present tense, and yes, the "sks" combination does sound funny when you stop to think about it. Asks.

Future tense would be "...tomorrow she will ask"

[verbix.com conjugation of the verb to ask](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/ask.html)